# Create a matrix using JTextFields or JTextAreas

Tags: java, matrix

I have to do make a program that has to be able to show a matrix in form of Jtextfields or Jtextareas, so that the user can write in them(a number of the matrix for each Jtextfield). 
The problem is that I have no idea how to create a custom JPanel with the size and quantity of Jtextfields that the user specifies(a different each time). 
I have already googled the question, to no avail.

Comment: Can provide more details regarding how you want the customised JPanel to behave?  Such, JPanel p = new MyJPanel(rows, cols) ??

Comment: I was planning to have a main panel, and then add to it the panel containing the TextFields. This panel would have a GridLayout depending on the size of the matrix. (n rows, n columns)

Comment: I havent seen that in class, as you may guess my teacher sucks badly but still makes us write difficult programs.

Comment: Ok, if it's a class assignment you probably want to go with something along the lines with what akf suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).  It is pretty simple to put together a grid together with a couple params (row and col count).  To paraphrase from the JavaDoc:

```
   public static void main (String[] args) {


         JPanel panel = new JPanel();     
         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
         panel.add(new JTextField("1"));
         panel.add(new JTextField("2"));
         panel.add(new JTextField("3"));
         panel.add(new JTextField("4"));
         panel.add(new JTextField("5"));
         panel.add(new JTextField("6"));
```

would result in a 3 row by 2 col grid of `JTextFields`

EDIT:

here is some more, in a class named `Demo`:

```
 public class Demo {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.print("please enter row and col on commandline");
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            new Demo(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

        }
    });

}


public Demo(int colCnt, int rowCnt) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();     
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(colCnt,rowCnt));

    for (int i =0; i < rowCnt*colCnt; i++) {
       panel.add(new JTextField(""+i));
    }

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Yea, that is exactly what i was planning to do, the problem is that I dont know how to add the number of JTextfields needed after the user tells the size of the matrix. It would be necessary to add them on runtime, and I cant find any way of doing that.

Comment: Was trying to compile and run your code so that I could give it a look and try, but got the following error:

Static Error: No constructor in Demo matches this invocation
    Arguments: ()
    Candidate signatures: Demo(int, int)

Comment: No. The error is indicating that the available constructor (`int,int`) was not being used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would build a 2d array of the text fields\areas. When you get the user input you can then initialize the arrays and "new up" all of the widgets. After adding all of them to the parent panel\frame you may have to do some calculation based on the used up size and resize your top level window. Aside from that, as already suggested, GridLayout will be a good choice for the direct parent component.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To change the appearance at runtime, all you need to do is replace the content with new components.
So depending on how you get your input, you replace the numbers given in akf's answer with the input.

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout( rows, columns));
```

and then to show the new panel you add it in the JFrame with

```
add( panel );
```

Your assignment however might be something along the lines of subclassing a JPanel to show a matrix. I get that impression in your wording. Then its a whole different solution.

If your only goal is to implement a matrix where you can edit values a JTable is by far the simplest. Put the following in a JFrame

```
    DefaultTableModel data = new DefaultTableModel(3 , 3);// rows, cols
    JTable table = new JTable(data);
    add(table);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
```

This would also simplify modifying the height and width of the matrix by using data.setRowCount( newValue ).